# Log motion detection in database using PHP and AXIS camera

Tags: php, axis

I'm trying to setup a new event trigger in my AXIS dashboard which triggers a PHP script. I've tried to create a new HTTP recipient in the dashboard which should go to motion.php uploaded on my website. There's nothing wrong with the PHP file because when I just go to the exact same URL in my browser the script writes data to the database. Now when I test the recipient in the dashboard, it either says 'Upload succesfull', or it returns a error 400. Does anyone know a solution or another way how I can achieve my purpose? Doesn't have to be related to PHP at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after trying a bunch of other things with no luck I finally got the idea to update the camera's software, which solved the issue immediately